# Fraction As Power: Alignment Problem (With Subscript)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, positioning, subscripts, fractions

I am trying to write an equation with the following code:

```
\begin{align}
  p_{e,i}(k)=\frac{4}{b_{i}(k)}
  \left(1-2^-\frac{b_{i}(k)}{2}\right)Q
  \left(
    \sqrt{\frac{3\ b_{i}(k)\gamma_{i}(k)}{2^{b_{i}(k)}-1}}
  \right),~\forall~i,~k, \text{even } b_{i}(k).
\label{evenpber}
\end{align}
```

Here I have the problem with the output highlighted part:
[image]

I want to see it like this one:
[image]

What will be the modification required to show output like this? Altruists plz respond!

Comment: You need to put the power within a `{}` group, as in `2^{-\frac{b_{i}(k)}{2}}`

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a extra pair of brackets like this:

```
\begin{align}
p_{e,i}(k)=\frac{4}{b_{i}(k)}\left(1-2^{-\frac{b_{i}(k)}{2}}\right)Q\left(\sqrt{\frac{3\ b_{i}(k)\gamma_{i}(k)}{2^{b_{i}(k)}-1}}\right),~\forall~i,~k, \text{even } b_{i}(k).
\label{evenpber}
\end{align}
```

MWE on https://www.latex4technics.com/?note=7ij0mu

This results in:
[image]